# What is meant by dynamic range when talking about probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

To provide some context, the exact sentence is

> for right-skewed data of the kind we consider here the method is especially sensitive to slight deviations of the data from the power-law model around xmin because most of the data, and hence most of the dynamic range of the CDF, lie in this region.

Thank you.

EDITS: I thought this was a common term used in statistics, so I didn't provide too much context, sorry about that. This is the paper this was taken from (it's at the end of section 3.3), https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1062.pdf. The author was discussing the performance of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic in determining a estimate for the xmin parameter when fitting a power law, and mentions how this method is sensitive to fluctuations at a certain range of the data.

Comment: That's not a lot of context. An actual reference might help more; dynamic range is not a typical term when discussing cdfs; it seems to come from sound engineering. It might be used when looking at measurements on some *instrument* but I've not seen it applied to cdfs.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just assumed this was a common usage of the term, added the reference

Comment: Oh okay. At least some of those authors are physicists; it's not so surprising they might use physics terms.